# confusion while using ng-if / ng-show / ng-hide

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-if

I have few div's inside my html. I am exporting the content to the PDF and PDF is downloaded when user click on he export button. I want few div's content **not to be exported/shown inside the PDF but it should be shown on the webpage**. I have used `ng-if="!isExporting"` to the div's whose content i don't want to show in the PDF and in the js code when the page is loaded i have assigned  `$scope.isExporting = false;` and when user clicked on export button, function `export()` is called where i have assigned  `$scope.isExporting = true`. Issue is still the content is exported to the PDF and shown. Please advice how to hide/restrict some div's content to be shown in the PDF but should be shown on the webpage.

Demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/Ik5O3rlKVLhzxz3ySw2g?p=preview

html code:

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" ng-controller="myDetailsController">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <br>
        <div style="margin-left: 5%">
          <button ng-click="export()">export</button>

          <form name="myDetailsform" novalidate>
            <div ng-if="addRow" class="row" style="border: 1px solid; width: 90%; margin-top: 2%;">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3" style="margin-left: 2%">
                  <div style="font-size: 4vmin;">Title1:</div>
                  <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': myDetailsform.title.$error.required }">
                    <input style="width: 100%; height: 230px;" type="text" name="title" class="form-control" ng-model="dataRow2Add.title" required/>
                  </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="col-md-8 summernote1">
                  <div style="font-size: 4vmin;" class="hideThis" ng-if="!isExporting">Details1 :</div>
                  <summernote config="summerOptions" ng-model="dataRow2Add.titleDetails" ng-if="!isExporting"></summernote>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="{{value.title}}" ng-repeat="(key, value) in myDetailsDetails" class="myDivClass">
              <div ng-hide="editData[value.myDetailsDetailsId]" class="row" style="border: 1px solid; width: 90%; margin-top: 2%;">
                <div class="row" style="margin-top: 1%">
                  <div class="col-md-10">
                    <span style="margin-left: 2%" class="hideThis" ng-if="!isExporting">
                      <label>Pick Date To : <input type="date" ng-model="panelCopyDate">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="copyPanelToDate($index, panelCopyDate)">GO</button>
                      </label>
                      <a style="margin-left: 5%; font-size: 100%;" href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="copyToNextWeek($index)">Pick Date To Next Week</a>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-1">
                    <a style="float:right; margin-right: 2%; margin-top: 1%; font-size: 24px;" href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="modifydataRow(value.myDetailsDetailsId, $index)" class="hideThis">Edit</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div style="font-size: 5vmin; color: #162E71;margin-left: 2%;">{{value.title}}</div>
                  <div style="margin-left: 3%; margin-top: 2%; margin-bottom: 2%" ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml{{value.titleDetails}}"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-8 summernote1" ng-if="isExporting">
                  <h2>Dont show/export this and below div content to PDF</h2>
                  <div style="font-size: 4vmin;" class="hideThis" ng-if="!isExporting">Details2 : hideBasicInfo :::{{hideBasicInfo}}</div>
                  <summernote config="summerOptions" ng-model="value.titleDetails" class="hideThis" ng-if="isExporting"></summernote>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

js code:

```
$scope.isExporting = false;

$scope.export = function() {
  var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'A4');
  var pdfName = 'test.pdf';
  var options = {};
  $scope.isExporting = true;
  $scope.hideBasicInfo = true;   
  var $divs = $('.myDivClass') //jQuery object of all the myDivClass divs
  var numRecursionsNeeded = $divs.length -1; //the number of times we need to call addHtml (once per div)
  var currentRecursion=0;

  function recursiveAddHtmlAndSave(currentRecursion, totalRecursions){
    //Once we have done all the divs save the pdf
    if(currentRecursion==totalRecursions){
      pdf.save(pdfName);
      $scope.isExporting = false;  //again isExporting should be assigned to false to make it visible on the webpage once the PDF is saved.
    } else {
      currentRecursion++;
      pdf.addPage();
      pdf.fromHTML($('.myDivClass')[currentRecursion], 15, 20, options, function() {
        console.log(currentRecursion);
        recursiveAddHtmlAndSave(currentRecursion, totalRecursions)
      });
    }
  }

  pdf.fromHTML($('.myDivClass')[currentRecursion], 15, 20, options, function() {
    recursiveAddHtmlAndSave(currentRecursion, numRecursionsNeeded);
  });
}
```

PS: I want to show the div's on the webpage but few of the div's should not be shown in the PDF. I tried using ng-show/ng-hide too but the behavior is same , it is not hiding the content in the PDF.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend wrapping the export logic in a short timeout after you set your `isExporting` and `hideBasicInfo` variables. This will give the DOM time to update before your export logic runs. The delay should not be noticeable to the user.

Example:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  var $divs = $('.myDivClass') //jQuery object of all the myDivClass divs
  var numRecursionsNeeded = $divs.length - 1; //the number of times we need to call addHtml (once per div)
  var currentRecursion = 0;

  function recursiveAddHtmlAndSave(currentRecursion, totalRecursions) {
    //Once we have done all the divs save the pdf
    if (currentRecursion == totalRecursions) {
      pdf.save(pdfName);
      $scope.isExporting = false; //again isExporting should be assigned to false to make it visible on the webpage once the PDF is saved.
    } else {
      currentRecursion++;
      pdf.addPage();
      pdf.fromHTML($('.myDivClass')[currentRecursion], 15, 20, options, function() {
        console.log(currentRecursion);
        recursiveAddHtmlAndSave(currentRecursion, totalRecursions)
      });
    }
  }

  pdf.fromHTML($('.myDivClass')[currentRecursion], 15, 20, options, function() {
    recursiveAddHtmlAndSave(currentRecursion, numRecursionsNeeded);
  });
}, 100);
```

**EDIT - Fixed so content will show again after export.**

We can accomplish this with two simple timeouts. You can even make the delays `1ms` and `2ms`. This will quickly hide the content you want hidden, perform the export, and show it again.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  pdf.fromHTML($('.myDivClass')[currentRecursion], 15, 20, options, function() {
    recursiveAddHtmlAndSave(currentRecursion, numRecursionsNeeded);
  });
}, 10)


setTimeout(function() {
  $scope.$apply(function() {
    $scope.isExporting = false;
    $scope.hideBasicInfo = false;
  });
}, 20);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/vg6ilw1IdJemKDLdL4EV?p=preview

Comment: It is hiding the content on the webpage and it is not showing again, i want the content to show on the webpage but only hide/dont export in the PDF.Please suggest.thanks

Comment: Sorry about that. Looks like we need to update your booleans again and use `$scope.apply` to save them. See updated version please.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you didn't pass any options to the pdfJS function. You can skip any elements by adding `ids` and passing them to `elementHandlers` option, as follows.

```
var elementHandler = {
  '#skipExport': function (element, renderer) {
    return true;
  }
};

var options = {
  'elementHandlers': elementHandler
};
```

In the HTML template, add the `id`:

```
<h2 id="skipExport">Don't show/export this and below div content to PDF</h2>
```

Updated plunkr can be seen [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/CaNEXS7HX30vkeQORMqJ?p=preview).